# Do we need 2 provisioning profiles to implement widget (extension) and main app in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, widget, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

What are the **precautions** taken to implement provisioning profiles?

How we can use the same bundle ID in app and extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same bundle ID for the app and the extension.
You need to create different App Ids and different provisioning profiles for both targets. Example:

**You project**

Bundle ID: com.example.project

Provisioning Development

Provisioning Distribution

**Widget**

Bundle ID: com.example.project.widget

Provisioning Development

Provisioning Distribution

Before create the provisioning profiles you need to enable app groups.

I recommend you to follow this helpful tutorial to configure it.

http://www.glimsoft.com/06/28/ios-8-today-extension-tutorial/